# Custom Facebook Login Button Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

To Creating a facebook login button, I followed facebook documentation and after that my login is working perfectly but I want to customize my button for that I tried lot things but nothing working.

**1) First I tried from xml like this:**

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/fbbutton_state"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Facebook"
        />
```

**2) Created custom class and extended LoginButton.**

```
public class CustomLoginButton extends LoginButton {

public CustomLoginButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs)
     this.setBackgroundColor(R.color.com_facebook_likeboxcountview_border_color);
    this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.my_own_icon, 0, 0, 0);
    this.setText("Facebook");
}

}
```

in this icon color changed but still text .

**3)And finally I tried in facebook sdk, I changed strings and style, it must work but no result**

```
<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button">Log in via Facebook</string> 


<style name="com_facebook_loginview_default_style" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">45dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/com_facebook_button_blue</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/com_facebook_loginview_text_color</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/com_facebook_loginview_text_size</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/com_facebook_loginview_padding_left</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
```

One difference I found in my login button and common SO login buttons is they are like: `<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton` and mine like this: `<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton`   but I think facebook upgraded this thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your XML :

Give the width and height of `com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton` **0**,
Place your custom button, give id and all to it,

Now go to your class, get a click listener of the custom button,
and place this line..

```
authButton.performClick();
```

Comment: is it work for google+ also? I tried but not getting any result.

Comment: leave it bro I did it.

Comment: In google we can use our custom button directly we don't need to use there button.

Comment: which SDK version you are using @priyanka ?

Comment: Sdk 4.0.1 , by default login functionality works, but if try to change the button it is giving me an error

Comment: Very ugly solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own simple Button and then use LoginManager for authorization

```
ArrayList<String> perms = new ArrayList<>();

perms.add("publish_actions");
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, perms);
```

Answer (score 0):

This workaround I had found long ago, add this line of code in your activity:

```
btnFb.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
btnFb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fb_drawable);
```

and do not forget to reset the default facebook button text in your xml as below:

```
facebook:com_facebook_logout_text=""
facebook:com_facebook_login_text=""
```

I hope you are using facebook sdk 4.x